# Adding two 32-bit constants store in memory using MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips, 32-bit

I'm trying to write an MIPS program that adds two 32-bit constants (stored in memory locations 0x1200 and 0x1204) and stores the result in 0xA200. I'm very new to the MIPS language and have been unsuccessful in figuring out how to first load the two 32-bits constants into a register, then how to store them into a specific area of memory. I understand that the lui and ori commands are needed to load the constant, but I'm not sure how to use them to access a specific area of memory. Any help on this would be appreciated!

This is what I have so far (the issues is I'm just loading the literal constant, not the address):

```
lui $t0, 0x1200
ori $t0, $t0, 0x1200
lui $t1, 0x1204
ori $t1, $t1, 0x1204
```

Comment: After you have the address in $t0, you do `la $t1,($t0)` to load  from that address into t1.

Comment: Since your addresses fit into the low 16 bits you don't need to use `lui` (but if you do, you should load a zero). So you can do `ori $t0, $zero, 0x1200`. Also depending on your assembler you may be allowed to use pseudoinstructions such as `la` or even `li` automatically doing the right thing.

Comment: That is loading 0x12001200 into `$t0` and 0x12041204 into `$t1`.  But you don't need to materialize the addresses into registers for those addresses, since they can be reached directly:  use `lw $t2, 0x1200($0)` and `lw $t3, 0x1204($0)`, for example.  Now, 0xA200 is too big an address to use in an `lw` (max is 0x7FFC) so you will have to materialize something in a register to do the store.  `la $t4, 0xA200` will work as will `ori $t4, $0, 0xA200`, then `sw $t5, 0($t4)` where `$t5` holds the result of your addition (of `$t2` and `$t3` in this example.